# How do I clear only 5 gold nuggets insted of all?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a shop and when I try to put "`/clear @p gold_nugget 5`" in a command block it wont work (I play in 1.11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax (in 1.11) is

```
clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

So in your case it will be

```
clear @p gold_nugget 0 5
```

The Minecraft Gamepedia wiki is a good place to start when learning the syntax of commands.